# Nested content_tag in a table not escaping html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I was creating a Presenter in Rails3 and having trouble with a nested content tag. A code excerpt is below:

```
def lesson_activity_row
  lesson.activities.collect do |lesson_activity|
    content_tag :tr do 
      concat(content_tag :td, lesson_activity.activity
      concat(content_tag :td, lesson_activity.duration
      concat(content_tag :td, lesson_activity.agent
     end
   end
end
```

In my view, I'd get the following:

```
["<tr><td>New Activity</td><td>5 Minutes</td><td>Teacher</td></tr>", "<tr><td>New Activity</td><td>5 Minutes</td><td>Teacher</td></tr>"]
```

Answer (score 1):

As I was looking, I couldn't really find any good answers to why this wasn't working and saw a host of questions that were either unanswered or weren't working for me. So, after looking at the methods I had available for Arrays and ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer, I came up with the following, which worked:

```
def lesson_activity_row
  lesson.activities.collect do |lesson_activity|
    content_tag :tr do 
      concat(content_tag :td, lesson_activity.activity
      concat(content_tag :td, lesson_activity.duration
      concat(content_tag :td, lesson_activity.agent
     end.to_s #note the to_s
   end.join.html_safe #note join.html_safe
end
```

Many of the solutions I saw included using `"joins"`, but content_tag here isn't returning an array. It's returning an instance of `ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer` and `#join` isn't a method for that object. `to_s`, however, is.

Of course, this `content_tag` is nested inside of `lesson.activities.collect`, which is an array and, of course, `#join` is a method that can be called on Array. And `#html_safe` escapes the html.

Hope this helps someone else!